# Assign value to spinner from number picker

Tags: java, android, spinner, numberpicker

I'm creating a fragment that contains number pickers and cancels *okay* buttons. Whenever I click the first spinner in the main activity, the spinner will pop out the fragment that contains number pickers. I select the number pickers values using `getValue()` method, but how to pass this value back to the spinner in main activity. I try to use `getposition()` method from spinner, but it won't works, because I didn't use `setAdapter()` method assign values to my spinner, I just want my spinner show the only one value retrieved from the fragment number pickers.

**OnCreate function**

```
s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
s.setOnTouchListener(onSpinnerTouchListener);
```

**Below is my onSpinnerTouchListener:**

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(TaxCalc.this); 
    View promptView = li.inflate(R.layout.frag_numpicker, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TaxCalc.this);
    builder.setView(promptView);

    builder.setTitle("Choose Amount of People");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int value = mNumberPicker.getValue();

        });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    mNumberPicker = (NumberPicker) promptView.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);


    array_spinner = new String[30];

    for (i = 0; i < 30 ; i++){
        array_spinner[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
    }

    mNumberPicker.setMaxValue(array_spinner.length-1);
    mNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);

    mNumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    mNumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(array_spinner);

    alertDialog =  builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Try to assign number picker value to local variable declare in MainActivity. and try to get value from it.

Comment: So far I can use get number picker values, but the problem is how to I assign value to spinner ?